# Internal Microphone Not Working When Running elementary OS on Galago UltraPro

Tags: audio, elementary-os

I am running elementary OS on a Galago UltraPro laptop. Originally, some of the hardware was not working because elementary uses the Ubuntu 12.04 kernel and the Galago UltraPro uses the relatively new Haswell processor and graphics drivers. However, I managed to get the graphics drivers working properly by running the command:

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring`.

Now, the only thing that appears to not be working is the internal mic.

I read here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2170623, that by plugging in a 3.5mm jack into the microphone jack, the internal mic would work again. When I tried this, the microphone works somewhat for a brief moment, but then fails again. I am imagining the microphone problems have something to do with the fact that elementary OS Luna is based upon Ubuntu 12.04 because when I boot into Manjaro Linux, the internal microphone works as expected.

Is there some way to fix this issue by updating sound drivers, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking for assistance in the elementary OS IRC channel, I was able to fix the problem. By running `alsamixer`, and then changing my Input Source from *mic* to *internal mic*, I was able to get my microphone working properly. I also lowered the levels of the internal microphone boost to get rid of some of the sharp static noise the was occurring when recording.